# Mocking Python modules across multiple test scripts

Tags: python, pytest

In my implementation script I have a line which logs a metric:

```
from datadog import statsd

def some_function:
    statsd.increment('some_metric')
```

From my test script, I assert that statsd.increment() is called by mocking out the datadog module:

```
datadog = Mock()
sys.modules['datadog'] = datadog

def test():
    some_function()
    datadog.statsd.increment.assert_called()
```

This works fine and passes. But as soon as I add ANOTHER script which calls `some_function()` without mocking datadog, that script runs beforehand and loads the real datadog module into the cache. The above test then fails because `some_function()` is no longer using the mock datadog, it uses the real (cached) datadog.

How can I address this? Is it possible to remove the module from the cache?

Comment: Are you saying it's failing because it's getting the "mock datadog" instead of the "real datadog"?

Comment: It passed when getting the mock datadog, now it fails because a previous running test has executed it, giving it the real datadog, which is then cached (so the mock cannot be used later on)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mock the `datalog` module inside your function `test`? As long as your other scripts are not running concurrently with your test, this may work. That way the mock itself will be set only when the function is called, instead of being set in your script scope.

Comment: The tests aren't running concurrently but it's the ordering that's the problem. A test which doesn't mock the module runs first and caches the module, so that it can't be mocked by any test running after that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unittest.mock.patch`. If you are using pytest you can do the same with the `monkeypatch` fixture.

```
from datadog import statsd
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

def some_function():
    statsd.increment()

def test_some_function():
    with patch('datadog.statsd', Mock()) as mock_statsd:
        some_function()
    mock_statsd.increment.assert_called()

test_some_function()
```